# Flash / Adobe 3.4 air fullscreen performance dip issue

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I'm creating an HD(1280x800) adobe air 3.4 app for desktop and in the background I'm doing a simple timeline animation that has circles emanating outward. These circles are pngs and I've tried both rendering as bitmap and not, and I tried as flash drawings with a blur on them. The problem I'm running into is that in fullscreen mode, the performance dips significantly. In window mode things run pretty smooth. I've tested this with the animation alone and it always happens. The stage size is the same as monitor res, and I've made sure that the stage isn't scaled, but still the performance problem persists. In the publish settings I have the acceleration set to GPU.

I was under the impression that flash can do all kinds of crazy 3D, so I'm just not understanding why this stupid simple timeline animation is causing so much grief. Can anyone fill me in on some info? Have a solution for the fullscreen performance problem? I have not been able to find a good answer or solution in all my searching.

UPDATE: looks like fullscreeninteractive, and not just full screen is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

dont use blur on animations. never. ever. that is the reason, people believe Flash is slow. Its not. But the banners are badly constructed, and use tons of filter. Go ahead, and implement blur filter in photoshop to a 3MP image. There will be a progressbar. It will take 1 sec. Blur is slow! If you want blur on your animation, record it, and store as a gif or fla. If you want working blur runtime, implement stage3D, and create an AGAL program that will render it on GPU.

Comment: Why pre-blur in Photoshop, when you can draw blurred image on BitmapData and save it for further use.

Comment: I've starting reading up on stage 3D and the starling "engine"

Comment: this still doesn't explain why fullscreen changes the performance though. it's the same resolution.

Comment: well, without code its hard to see. But probably the image is bigger, the blur is applied to a 4x bigger screen.. you can have any type of bugs making it slower.. try profiling your app (pro feature in FB).. If you watch the cpu usage of the app, you could see, that in small mode it eats nearly one processor..

Comment: I just found that using fullscreeninteractive eliminates the framerate drop, soo woo for that. I'll test more to be sure.